# Process files only if all files with the unique 11-character code exist

Tags: c#

I'm using the ERP BEXT. BEXT generates 4 kind of files, which have to be imported on a server. All file names contain a special `11 character` code as seen in the image below.

[image: An exemple of the 4 kind of files.]

Before importing, the files. I need to check if the 4 file exist.

I thought of using the Method : `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` and use the Method `Substring` to grab the 4 filename but I'm a bit lost. Because you cannot use `Substring` on a table.

```
string[] txt = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/ngallouj/Desktop/Script/test", "*.txt").Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).ToArray();
string[] top = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/ngallouj/Desktop/Script/test", "*.txt").Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < txt.Length;i++)
{
    i++;

    Console.WriteLine("Fichier de Type 1 : " + txt[i - 2]);

    for (int j = 0; j < top.Length; j++)
    {
        j++;
        Console.WriteLine("Fichier Type 2 :" + top[j - 1]);

        if (txt[i - 1] == top[j - 1])
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("//ALICE/interface.exe");
            //The Batch sort the files, without issue.
        }
        else
        {
            //No matc exiting the P.
        }
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: using `foreach` to iterate through the items themselves might give you a bit of an overview. It works the same as `for`, but instead of having a variable that counts the positions in the iteration you have, at hand, the item being iterated over itself.

Comment: And for what its worth, it might be a good idea to grab all the filenames in the directory, and strip the strings of everything except the ID. Then you have a selection on which you can call `Distinct()`, so you have the seperate IDs. If you have a list of the seperate IDs you can go back to the full array of all filenames and check if every ID is mentioned 4 times in the array.

Comment: Thanks for your help man, That's exactly what I want to do, That's why I've created 2 tables to store the filename. But I figured out that I couldn't use substring on the table to get the ID. I'll look at that Distinct() method

Comment: From your image sample, I can't tell what is the full name of the file. Do they have `.txt` extension? Is that why you use `GetFiles` with `*.txt` argument? Sorry, I don't understand what you are `trying to achieve` in the code - do you mind explaining? And I don't see a 11 digit number, there is only a 9 digit number with a `BP` prefix

Comment: You can't, but you can iterate over the items and check the substring on each individual item. Ill provide you with an answer if you give me a second.

Comment: Yep, Basicly I've 2 extensions : " .txt & .top" there is 2 .txt file & 2 .top file. I need to check if those 4 files exist before calling my Batch. I'll do item by item

Comment: But extension doesn't really matter, the ID is 11 "characters", sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will get you a dictionary where the keys are the File IDs, and the values are the number of times it has encountered that FileID in the directory.

```
    public string ExtractIDFromFileName(string filename)
    {
        return filename.Split('_').Last();
    }

    public Dictionary<string,int> GetDictOfIDCounts()
    {
        List<string> allfiles = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/ngallouj/Desktop/Script/test", "*.txt").Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).ToList();
        allfiles.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/ngallouj/Desktop/Script/test", "*.top").Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).ToList());
        Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        foreach(var x in allfiles)
        {
            string fileID = ExtractIDFromFileName(x);
            if (dict.ContainsKey(fileID))
            {
                dict[fileID]++;
            }
            else
            {
                dict.Add(fileID, 1);
            }
        }
        return dict;
    }
```

All you'll have to do is check whether the ID's you need actually have been found 4 times, and those ID's are the ones you import.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Contains()` method to check if the filename contains the string you are looking for:

```
 string[] txt = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/ngallouj/Desktop/Script/test", "*.txt")
.Select(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x))
.Where(x => x.Contains("BP011910513")).ToArray();
```

Or if you want to get all those files which their name without extension ends with the given string:

```
 string[] txt = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/ngallouj/Desktop/Script/test", "*.txt")
.Select(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x))
.Where(x => x.EndsWith("_BP011910513")).ToArray();
```

To grab 11 char Id:

```
 string[] IDs = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/ngallouj/Desktop/Script/test", "*.txt")
.Select(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x).Split("_").Last())
.Where(x => x.Length == 11).ToArray();
```

Or:

```
     string[] IDs = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/ngallouj/Desktop/Script/test", "*.txt")
    .Select(x => { 
var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x);
return name.Length >= 11; name.SubString(name.Length-11): "";
}).Where(x => x.Length == 11).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem, is that I'll have to write manually the filename in my program, I would be able to pick the 11 last Digit of the String that' , and then compare it

Comment: well in contains, you can use a variable like: `string char11 = "BP011910513";` and then: `x.Contains(char11)`

Comment: you have problem getting these 11 chars?

Comment: There's thousand of files :-)

Comment: @NaïmGallouj I get that, in order to help, I need to know which part you are having trouble.

Comment: the above query will return only the files that endwith 11 characters you have given

Comment: Grabing the ID of all files, that's all pretty much.

Comment: Sick Thanks pal !

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is a good way to solve these kind of problems

```
var groupedFiles = from f in Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/ngallouj/Desktop/Script/test", "*.t*")
                    let match = Regex.Match(f, @"([a-zA-Z0-9]{11})(?:\.top|\.txt)$")
                    where match.Success
                    let groupKey = match.Groups[1].Value
                    group f by groupKey into fileGroupItem
                    let fileGroup = fileGroupItem.ToArray()
                    where fileGroup.Length == 4
                    select new { GroupKey = fileGroupItem.Key, FileGroup = fileGroup };
```

You can adjust the `Directory.GetFiles` appropriately to fetch all the relevant files, if fetching `*.t*` will bring a lot of unwanted files and reduce performance.

Let me explain the query, we fetch all the relevant files and match against the Regex to find out the 11 digit alpha-numeric ``groupKey`. Now we group the files using this key and eliminate all groups which do not have exactly 4 items.
This gives us`groupedFiles`which is an`IEnumerable` of all file groups which have all the 4 files.

The Regex, can lend you with flexibility in the future and the LINQ query is easily extensible to add more processing.

The biggest reason, I would go for such a solution is its readability.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Way to Grab the ID, & count the iteration.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int w = 0;
        int zig = 0;
        string[] IDs = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/ngallouj/Desktop/Script/test", "*.txt")
        .Select(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x).Split('_').Last())
        .Where(x => x.Length == 11).ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < IDs.Length; i++)
        {
            i++;
            Console.WriteLine("" + IDs[i - 1]);

            if (IDs[w] != IDs[i-1])
            {
                w++;

            }else

            {
                zig++;
                if (zig == 4)
```

{

```
                    Console.WriteLine("l'idée ci-dessous apparait : 4 fois");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            } 

        }
```